# rock, paper, scissors, on khan academy

Tags: javascript, var

I am programing a rock paper scissors game on khan academy so I can have visuals, but `var compare = function(choice1, choice2)` isn't working properly. html it works fine thought. 
inserted the rest of my code(keep in mind the visuals and buttons aren't

```
background(0, 0, 0);
var userChoice = text("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors? Refresh to play again!", 25, 50); //starting text
var choice1 = userChoice;
var choice2 = computerChoice;
var winner = 25;
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} // Abover: computers choice, randomly chooses rock, paper or scissors
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        text("It is a draw!!! Try again!", winner, 50); // If both choices are the same it is a draw
    }
};
if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        text("rock Wins!!!", winner, 50);
    } else {
        text("paper Wins!!!", winner, 50); // If the choices are rock and scissors, rock wins, if not then paper wins
    }
}
if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        text("paper Wins!!!", winner, 50);
    } else {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            text("scissors Wins!!!", winner, 50); // If the choices are rock and paper, paper wins, if not then scissors
        }
        if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                text("rock Wins!!!", winner, 50);
            } else {
                if (choice2 === "paper") {
                    text("paper Wins!!!", winner, 50); // If the choices are scissors and rock, rock wins, if not then paper
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Above: compares the two choices to determine the winner, winner is rock, paper or scissors, not computer or user
text("User Choice: ", 20, 80 + userChoice);
text("Computer Choice: ", 20, 70 + computerChoice);
compare(userChoice, computerChoice); // Above: the message that tells the user who won
//Below: everything to do with the buttons
var squareW = 50;
var squareH = 50;
draw();
rect(75, 200, squareW, squareH); //left square
rect(175, 200, squareW, squareH); //middle square
rect(275, 200, squareW, squareH); //right square
```

Comment: your compare function only tests if they are equal - format your code correctly and it's obvious what is happening

Comment: I edited your code, all I did was indent the code correctly, so you can see why the compare function is not what you think it should be

Comment: thanx for that i have fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have figured it out by now, but I gave it a try anyway out of curiosity. I made a few changes as you can see below. I had to rearrange some functions and do some nesting so that that the user would have a chance to make her choice before the result was calculated. I also removed some code to avoid text overlap. I'll leave it to you to clean it up a little more, but your game now works correctly for every possible combination of user and computer choices.

```
background(0, 0, 0);
var userChoice;
var computerChoice;
var winner = 200;

text("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?", 25, 22);
var squareW = 50;
var squareH = 50;
draw();
text("ROCK", 75, 180, squareW, squareH);
rect(75, 200, squareW, squareH); //Choose rock by clicking anywhere to the left of this square's right edge.
text("PAPER", 175, 180, squareW, squareH);
rect(175, 200, squareW, squareH); //Choose paper by clicking anywhere between the left square's right edge and the right square's left edge.
text("SCISSORS", 275, 180, squareW + 10, squareH);
rect(275, 200, squareW, squareH); //Choose scissors by clicking anywhere to the right of this square's left edge.

mousePressed = function() {
    //I wasn't sure how to keep the above background, squares and text from disappearing without repeating the code within this function.
    background(0, 0, 0);
    text("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?", 25, 22);
    draw();
text("ROCK", 75, 180, squareW, squareH);
rect(75, 200, squareW, squareH); //left square
text("PAPER", 175, 180, squareW, squareH);
rect(175, 200, squareW, squareH); //middle square
text("SCISSORS", 275, 180, squareW + 10, squareH);
rect(275, 200, squareW, squareH); //right square    

    if(mouseX < 125) {
        userChoice = "rock";
    } else if(mouseX < 225) {
        userChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        userChoice = "scissors";
    }

    computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var compare = function(userChoice, computerChoice) {
    if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        text("YOU BOTH WIN! YAY!", winner, 50);
    }
};
if (userChoice === "rock") {
    if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
        text("YOU'RE A WINNER!!!", winner, 50);
    } else if (computerChoice === "paper") {
        text("YOU'RE A LOSER!!!", winner, 50); // I don't include a final else statement here because it would cause overlapping text and draws are already accounted for.
    }
}
if (userChoice === "paper") {
    if (computerChoice === "rock") {
        text("YOU'RE A WINNER!!!", winner, 50);
    } else if (computerChoice === "scissors") {
        text("YOU'RE A LOSER!!!", winner, 50);
    }
}
if (userChoice === "scissors") {
    if (computerChoice === "paper") {
        text("YOU'RE A WINNER!!!", winner, 50);
    } else if (computerChoice === "rock") {
        text("YOU'RE A LOSER!!!", winner, 50);
    }
}

// I figured it would make more sense to specify if the user won rather than rock, paper or scissors.
text("Your Choice: " + userChoice, 50, 50);
text("Computer's Choice: " + computerChoice, 50, 100);
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
};
```